# Sharing to pinterest with Branch.io

Tags: android, pinterest, branch.io

Has anyone had any luck sharing to pinterest with branch.io? I tried their own demo app and that doesn't work either.

```
    BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
            .setTitle("title")
            .setContentImageUrl(imageUrl)
         .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC);
```

Any workaround or extra steps I need to take to get pinterest sharing working?

Answer (score 0):

I did what I could and contacted Pinterest directly with your issue, after reproducing it locally. I received the following responses:

> Madeline (Pinterest Help) Dec 8, 10:08 PST
>
> Hi Evan,
>
> I have shared this information with our dev team and they are doing
>   what they can to get this fixed.
>
> Thanks.
>
> — Madeline
>
> Madeline (Pinterest Help) Dec 19, 09:55 PST
>
> Hi Evan,
>
> I hate to be the bearer of bad news but our dev team decided not to
>   prioritize this bug and won't be fixing it. I'm very sorry!
>
> — Madeline

Please contact them directly, Ryye, the more reports the higher the chance of resolution, I'm sorry for the trouble.